# IE 11 memory consumption increases even after reload

Tags: internet-explorer, memory-leaks

[image: ever increasing - Pressed F5 hundred times]

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this IE 11 behavior. It is a pretty standard web page with jquery and knockout plus some web fonts. The users report that the site becomes increasingly sluggish until IE eventually craches.

This is not a single-page-application, the users frequently navigates between different .html pages and even pressing F5 doesn't prevent IE from accumulating something in memory. I have absolutely no idea what IE is piling up in memory as snapshots taken at different points in time contains exactly the same data.

The content of cookies, localStorage and sessionStorage is constant as well.

What will cause IE memory usage to keep increasing even after a page reload?

Comment: use WPT, run WPRUI, select "Virtual Alloc" and under scenario "Internet Explorer", capture a bit of the grow and analyze the memory usage grow inside WPA: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-49-WPT-Memory-Analysis-VirtualAlloc

Comment: was the WPT helpful? Can you see what happens?